# Does the developer commentary contain spoilers?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Pillars of Eternity has a developer commentary that I can turn on in the options. I'm interested in listening to it, and strongly suspect that I'll never get around to a second playthrough to only do it after I've beaten the game.

If I turn the developer commentary on, will it spoil any of the game's plot, or will it just talk about things I've already seen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the developer commentary does contain some spoilers, though not huge ones (that I have found). Usually it is a small spoiler about what is about to take place.

An example, at the very beginning of the game, the commentary spoiled the first event that was about to take place (spoiler below):

> The developer commentary discussed the ambush that was about to take place on the caravan.